# query prisma relation to return child field if parent field meets condition

Tags: prisma, gql, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I have two models: `Post` model and a `PostItem` model. A `Post` can have multiple `PostItems`.

```
model Post {
  id                  Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title               String   @db.VarChar(300)
  postItemNoteStatus  String   @db.Text

  postItems           PostItem[]    
}

model PostItem {
   id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
   postId  Int
   url     String? @db.VarChar(1000)
   note    String? @db.VarChar(300)
   
   post Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
}
```

I want to find a `Post` and return all of its `PostItems`, but only include the `note` field in `PostItem` if `postItemNoteStatus` is `visible`. I would like to do this in one query. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
db.post.findFirst({
  where: { id},
  include: { postItems: true }
})

if(post.postItemNoteStatus === 'hidden') {
 post.postItems.forEach((pi) => {
    delete pi.note;
 });
}
```

This works, but I have to manually delete notes if the `postItemNoteStatus` is `hidden`. I would like to be able to do this elegantly in a query. Is this possible given the models and relation I have?

Comment: Check the example in the filtering guide: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting

Comment: @SlothOverlord i've taken a look before at this doc, doesn't have the scenario I am looking for

Comment: I don't think it's possible to achieve this in a single query. It might be possible through Raw SQL query. Do you face any performance issue due to multiple queries?